# How to create "or" statement

Tags: java, xml, xslt

I had a problem with conditional statement in XSLT. I have simple conditional block with one variable $address and one constant in $buyer variable:

```
 <xsl:if test="$address=$buyer>
     (.... some content)
 </xsl>
```

Now I got additional variable $supplier that need also the same content like $buyer
So I need something like `if test="$address=$buyer ||/or $address=$supplier"` but followed code break my program:

```
 <xsl:if test="$address=$buyer || $address=$supplier" >
```

My question is how to make this conditional statement correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use XPath operators. In this case "or":

More info:

http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_operators.asp

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake in my answer. Please, see updated version.

Comment: `|` is the operator to take a union of two node sets, `or` is the boolean OR operator.  They're interchangable in certain circumstances but not everywhere.